# Add List Webpart to Oslo Masterpage

Tags: 2013, web-part, master-page, front-end

SharePoint 2013

In a subsite I'm developing that uses the Oslo masterpage, it seems that the structrual navigation (side navigation) is used on top while the global navigation (Seattle's top bar) is missing. Rather than finding a way to display the global navigation (and change the whole site collection), I want to use a custom webpart that displays a list of links that can take the place of the side navigation menu.

The question is that how can I put such a webpart in the masterpage so that it displays itself throughout the subsite and only that particular subsite?

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to create a new master page by copying the oslo.html. Then compare it with Seattle.html and see the difference. The top navigation code looks similar to this (see below) that is missing in oslo.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">-->
        <!--SPM:<Template_Controls>-->
            <!--SPM:<asp:SiteMapDataSource 
                ShowStartingNode="False"
                SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" 
                id="topSiteMap" 
                runat="server"
                StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>-->
        <!--SPM:</Template_Controls>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
    <a name="startNavigation"></a> 
    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:AspMenu 
            ID="TopNavigationMenu" 
            Runat="server" 
            EnableViewState="false"
            DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
            AccessKey="&lt;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&gt;"
            UseSimpleRendering="true"
            UseSeparateCss="false"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            StaticDisplayLevels="2"
            AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
            SkipLinkText="" />-->
            <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/menu-21.css" /><div id="zz7_TopNavigationMenu" class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox"><ul id="zz9_RootAspMenu" class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static"><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" title="Default Publishing Site" href="#" accesskey="1"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Default Publishing Site</span></span></a></li></ul></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->

<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```